# SQL query to return matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of rows with one column of actual data. The goal is display this data in Matrix format. The numbers of Column will remain same, the number of rows may vary.

For example:

- I have 20 records. If I have 5 columns - then the number of rows would be 4
- I have 24 records. I have 5 columns the number of rows would be 5, with the 5th col in 5th row would be empty.
- I have 18 records. I have 5 columns the number of rows would be 4, with the 4th & 5th col in 4th row would be empty.

I was thinking of generating a column value against each row. This column value would b,e repeated after 5 rows. But I cannot the issue is "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations"

Not sure how it can be achieved.

Any advice will be helpful.

Further Addition - I have managed to generate the name value association with column name and value. Example - 
Name1 Col01 
Name2 Col02 
Name3 Col03 
Name4 Col01 
Name5 Col02

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result

Comment: You wish to split column to multiple parts when SQL is returning results or when displaying them on web?

Comment: I would do this in the client program not in sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to assign a sequential integer from 0 up. Then group by the result of integer division whilst pivoting on the remainder.

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT number, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) -1 AS RN
FROM master..spt_values
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN RN%5 = 0 THEN number END) AS Col1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN%5 = 1 THEN number END) AS Col2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN%5 = 2 THEN number END) AS Col3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN%5 = 3 THEN number END) AS Col4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN%5 = 4 THEN number END) AS Col5
FROM T
GROUP BY RN/5
ORDER BY RN/5
```

Comment: Can you please help further? Is there a way to prevent returning NULL for the rows for which entry is not there. To elaborate  - if I have a 5X5 matrix and I have 23 records in the table. How should I prevent returning NULLs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In general:

- SQL is for retrieving data, that is all your X records in one column
- Making a nice display of your data is usually the job of the software that queries SQL, e.g. your web/desktop application.

However if you really want to build the display output in SQL you could use a `WHILE` loop in connection with `LIMIT` and `PIVOT`. You would just select the first 5 records, than the next ones until finished.

Here is an example of how to use `WHILE`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms178642.aspx